# Training Bayesian Classifier

Tags: python-3.x, naivebayes

I'm trying to train and test a Bayesian Classifier in Python.

These lines of code are from an example I found [here](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Machine-Learning-errors?pid=42135), but I don't understand what they do.

```
train_labels = np.zeros(702)
train_labels[351:701] = 1
train_matrix = extract_features(train_dir)
```

There is a similar code block later in the test set:

```
test_matrix = extract_features(test_dir)
test_labels = np.zeros(260)
test_labels[130:260] = 1
```

Wondering what this does and how I can apply it to a different classification example? What do the numbers in `[]` mean?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code, referenced in your post, is training a binary classifier with Naive-Bayes and SVC model.

```
train_labels = np.zeros(702)
train_labels[351:701] = 1
train_matrix = extract_features(train_dir)
```

This is setting the label for 702 records with all 0 initially. and sets the later half with 1. Binary labels like: spam or ham, true or false, etc. 
The extract_features builds the {(docid, wordid)->wordcount,..} which is input to these models.

Once you train the model, you need to see how well it performs against a test set. Here you are using 260 records as test set with first half all 0s and the later half all 1s.

```
test_matrix = extract_features(test_dir)
test_labels = np.zeros(260)
test_labels[130:260] = 1
```

Finally, you run the prediction against the test set and evaluate how close is the accuracy to the test_set of both of these models (NB and SVC).

Comment: Thank you so much! From what I understood, the binary setting can be anything as long as they are distinct categories? Thanks

Comment: Also, are the records are based on the text file orderings in the directory?

Comment: No order used. Naive Bayes is a simple bag of word model where the text ordering is not used.

Comment: So how does the labelling of records work if first half are 0 and second half are 1?

Comment: Sorry. I thought you meant word order. The record order should match the training label order. but the word order in the each record don't matter. thats why they call it naive bayes.